# how do you goto in mac shell (like a in windows .bat)?

Tags: macos, shell, sh, goto

The .bat equivalent is:

```
:one
<<run program>>
goto :two

:two
<<run program>>
goto :one

end
```

Can a .sh do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually no exact replacement. In `bash` programming, you can define functions, so you might do something like

```
one() {
    # Some stuff
    two
}

two() {
    # Some more stuff
    one
}
```

Although eventually that'll run out of stack space; hopefully there's some circumstances under which you'll include code to stop the recursion. I realize this is just a straw man example, but `bash` would let you use other forms of loops here which would work better; for example:

```
while true
do
    # Some stuff
    # Some more stuff
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The Unix shell allows for structured programming, so there's no need for `goto`.

```
while true; do
    <<some things here>>
    <<more things here>>
done
```

Comment: "while 1" will only work if there is a command named '1' in the PATH.  You probably mean "while :" or "while true"

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are trying to accomplish using the goto statement can probably be expressed without it in bash, specifically by writing functions or by using an infinite while loop (with a way of breaking out of it).  By the way the pseudocode you wrote will eventually crash unless you have some exit condition specified in one or two

Comment: The code pauses at the <<>> part, and continues when the program that was at the <<>> ends.